# Checkbox que troca imagem em javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu preciso, em um projeto, de uma interação que consiste em 5 checkboxes, que ao marcados, mudam a src de imagens na página.

Eu já achei um pronto, na verdade:
http://jsfiddle.net/y015gunx/1/

O que eu quero fazer é **criar mais checkboxes para mudar a source de outras imagens,** dentro do mesmo script.

Estou tentando fazer isso há um tempo, mas não consigo (por não conhecer nada de Javascript).

Esse script é a melhor solução para isso? Como eu faria para adicionar mais uma imagem e outro checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você for ter mais de uma opção pra mudar a mesma `imagem` então minha recomendação é utilizar `radio` ao invés de `checkbox` e separar ele em grupos. O problema do `checkbox` que eu penso seria quando você selecionar 2 `checkboxs` para alterar uma mesma imagem, qual prevalece e por que deixaria os 2 checados?

### Exemplo:

```js
function mudarBg(valor, idImg) {
    document.getElementById(idImg).src = valor;
}
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByName('bgradio1')[0].click();
    document.getElementsByName('bgradio2')[0].click();
}
```

```css
#sua_img {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

#sua_img2 {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="bgradio1" onclick="mudarBg(this.value, 'sua_img')" value="http://igshalon.com/iswp/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/numero-1.jpg">Imagem 1.1<br/>
    
<input type="radio" name="bgradio1" onclick="mudarBg(this.value, 'sua_img')" value="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/leroy-production//uploads/img/products/numero_para_residencia_numero_2_14_5_cmx10_cm_cromado_bemfixa_87963715_0001.jpg_1800x1800.jpg">Imagem 1.2 <br/>
    
<input type="radio" name="bgradio1" onclick="mudarBg(this.value, 'sua_img')" value="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/N%C3%BAmero_3_(manuscrito).svg/305px-N%C3%BAmero_3_(manuscrito).svg.png">Imagem 1.3 <br/>
    
<input type="radio" name="bgradio2" onclick="mudarBg(this.value, 'sua_img2')" value="http://cdn3.colorir.com/desenhos/pintar/numero-4_2.png">Imagem 2.1 <br/>
    
<input type="radio" name="bgradio2" onclick="mudarBg(this.value, 'sua_img2')" value="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/runescape/images/c/c1/N%C3%BAmero_5.png/revision/latest?cb=20120802141805&path-prefix=pt">Imagem 2.2 <br/>

<div style="display: inline-flex">
    <img id="sua_img"/> 
    
    <img id="sua_img2"/>
</div>
```

### Explicação:

A função mudarBg recebe 2 parâmetros:

- `valor` - é o value que está no input, no meu exemplo coloquei a `URL` da imagem.
- `idImg` - é o id da `<img>` que você quer mudar, exemplo os 3 primeiros radio alteram a primeira imagem enquanto os 2 últimos radio alteram a segunda imagem.

O atributo `name` do `input` agrupa os radio, então todos que possuem `bgradio1` só pode ter um selecionado e a mesma coisa pro `bgradio2`.

-

### Exemplo com `checkbox`:

```js
function mudarBg(campo, idImg) {
    if (campo.checked) {
        document.getElementById(idImg).style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + campo.value + ')';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(idImg).style.backgroundImage = '';
    }
}
```

```css
#sua_img {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url('http://blog.trifork.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Html5_canvas_logo.png')
}

#sua_img2 {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url('http://mohitrickzz.heck.in/files/flags-dd-css.jpg')
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="mudarBg(this, 'sua_img')" value="http://jstricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/javascript-redirect.png">Imagem 1<br/>
    
<input type="checkbox" onclick="mudarBg(this, 'sua_img2')" value="http://php.quicoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/css3.jpg">Imagem 2 <br/>
    

<div style="display: inline-flex">
    <img id="sua_img"/> 
    
    <img id="sua_img2"/>
</div>
```

A função `mudarBg` agora recebe o campo inteiro, através dele como saber se ele foi `checked` e qual seu valor.

O segredo está atribuindo `CSS` com um `background-image` padrão e quando eu seleciono o `checkbox` eu atributo um novo `background-image` direto no `style`. Dessa forma quando eu removo o `checked` ele só limpa o atributo `style` e mantém o `CSS`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, Maicon. Mas eu queria um checkbox para mudar a source de uma imagem, enquanto teria outro checkbox para mudar a source de outra imagem,e assim por diante, e não uma imagem e vários checkboxes, e que eu pudesse também desmarcar um checkbox, voltando assim a imagem associada a ele para a source anterior.  É possivel fazer isso usando radio como você usou?

Comment: @BrunoGarcia Se você olhar no meu exemplo eu tenho 2 imagens, a segunda está mais pra baixo.

Comment: @BrunoGarcia Alterei o código, fico mais visível.

Comment: @BrunoGarcia A lógica pro `checkbox` seria a mesma, vou criar outro snippet

Comment: Neste caso, eu só preciso de 2 sources, e que elas se alternem pela condição da caixa estar marcada ou não. Ou seja, se a caixa 1 for marcada, a imagem associada a ela é A, se a caixa for desmarcada é B, e isso não afeta em nada a caixa 2 e a caixa 3, por exemplo. Eu só preciso desses dois estados pra cada imagem e cada checkbox, por isso acho que não é possivel usar radio, como você fez. Não deixei isso claro na minha pergunta inicial, perdão. Veja o exemplo:http://jsfiddle.net/y015gunx/1/ é exatamente isso, só que eu não sei como colocar mais imagens pra outros checkboxes.

Comment: @BrunoGarcia Adicionei um exemplo com `checkbox`

Comment: Muito obrigado, Maicon, o segundo exemplo (com checkbox) atende perfeitamente e com isso já consigo construir o que eu tinha em mente.